# Need help on implement action button with SHAREKIT for xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook

I am implement my app with Facebook with Share kit. I am using Action button in the toolbar with below code. I have error on below line when I click the action button or when the share method got called. Please enlighten me!

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender {
NSString *text;
 NSLog(@"myButtonHandlerAction");

if (TextView.selectedRange.length > 0)
    text = [TextView.text substringWithRange:TextView.selectedRange];

else
    text = TextView.text;

SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:text];
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];

     //this line is causing error
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

Error message is 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: view != nil'

Comment: do you get the error when your share method is called?

Are you sure your text is not nil?

Comment: Yes when the share method is called. It is actually a text from the files in the view. Could this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if HKItem *item = [SHKItem text:@"TEST TEXT"]; works

if it does, then you know whats the problem!

Comment: Sorry, It did not work.
 *** Assertion failure in -[SHKActionSheet _presentSheetFromView:above:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UIActionSheet.m:1720
2011-08-04 22:18:38.176